# nsExec::ExectoStack not providing expected result

Tags: windows, nsis

I'm trying to execute following command using ExectoStack

```
echo "hello.world.url=Hello:World" | C:\cygwin64\bin\gawk.exe -F= "{print $1}"
```

The output on cmd comes out to be as expected

```
"hello.world.url
```

When I do this using nsis as:

```
nsExec::ExectoStack 'cmd /c echo "hello.world.url=Hello:World" | C:\cygwin64\bin\gawk.exe -F= "{print $1}"'
pop $0
pop $1
```

I get the output as

```
return code = 0
output = "hello.world.url=Hello:World"
```

What my guess is that $1 contains output of first command(echo) and somehow not picking up the output of successive command(gawk). Please let me know if I am missing out on any step.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work fine for me:

```
Section 
nsExec::ExectoStack 'cmd /c dir "%windir%\system32" | findstr /I "kernel32"'
pop $0
pop $1
DetailPrint "Return=$0"
DetailPrint "Output=|$1|"
SectionEnd
```

but what you might be forgetting is that $1 is a NSIS variable! Try escaping it as `$$1`.

Comment: If I pipe the output to cmd inbuilt commands it works. But it is not working with cygwin

Comment: And you fixed the $1 issue? findstr is a .exe as well, not a internal command.

Comment: Okay. When I use its as $$1 it then prints "$1" as output.